# Sitecore - how to persist a Layout change

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I developed a Sitecore control I'd like to put into a layout on one page.

In this case it's a registration page, and my control is defined as a sublayout.

What I did is went into the Page Editor interface, and plonked the control into one of the placeholders.

What I want to do now is to create a package only containing the information that this control is on this particular page, without affecting e.g. the content or subitems of this node.

Can you please advise on the best way to create such packag, what exactly to select in the Package Designer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the Package Designer gives you granular control to include just specific fields of an item. You need to add the item as whole.

Comment: +1. The smallest unit Sitecore Package operates with is item.

Answer (score -1):

You should configure layouts and renderings in the presentation details of an item OR even better in the `__Standard Values` of the template.
You can call the presentation details dialog through the content editor. Just select an item in the content tree, click on the `Presentation` tab in the top ribbon and select `Details`. You can configure all layouts/renderings for the selected item here.
But ff you want to prevent content changes you really SHOULD configure the presentation in the `__Standard Values` of the template. This is also the way, which is recommended by Sitecore. If you do this, the layouts are all you have to put into a package.